# does binding nullable string in xml causes error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using a nullable String `hasName: String?`  and binding in xml as

```
android:visibility="@{myModel. hasName().equals(`true`)??View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

Is this correct?

In the above line what happens if **hasName** is null?

Comment: assign it null yourself, see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your statement will compile. You have `??` and `:` that could not be use as you expect.